# Keep TcpListerner in Idle state C#

Tags: c#, tcplistener

i have these code for a server and client program. client program sends a value to server and server reads it. but here after first message, server shuts down.
i want it to be listerning until the full application shuts down. so after 1 connection closes, it will wait for next connection and so on.

```
internal static async Task ServerHandler()
    {
        Console.Writeline("starting server...");
        IPAddress b = IPAddress.Any;
        TcpListener Server = new TcpListener(b, 5550);            
        Server.Start();            
        Console.Writeline("Server Started Sucessfully!");
        Console.Writeline("Waiting for Connection...");
        TcpClient Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient(); 

        string clientIPAddress = "Connected! => " + IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
        Console.Writeline(clientIPAddress);

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {                
            try
            {
                Stream MessageStream = Client.GetStream();
                bytesRead = MessageStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string recivedMessage = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.Writeline(recivedMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Client.Close();
            Server.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your client connects, sends a "message", then disconnects. If you want your server to be able to support more than one connection, ever, it needs to have `AcceptTcpClient` itself in a loop. But also note my quotes above - TCP itself is an *endless stream of bytes*. You are not guaranteed that each call of `Write` at one end will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Read` at the other end. Each call to `Read` *could* return a single `byte` at a time and still satisfy the contract.

Comment: Also, `catch (IOException)
            {
                break;
            }` is *terrible* code. If something is going wrong, you've given yourself **no** opportunity to discover what the problem was specifically.

Comment: i just started with tcp service to send commands from my pc to a program running on server. so the program should be able to recive commands 24 hrs a day. 
the client sends a message and then disconnects as the command is obv just 2 words and the processing of the command is done on the server program. right now the server program wont recive any more commands other than first one.
and also the server program should be able to handle multiple connections but i cant get the part where the server program will keep on listerning even after 1 client disconnects or sends message.

Comment: and yes i agree that the code is very poor as i am just getting the basic part working still. and didnt encounter any errors so far so didnt really went after it

Comment: [TcpListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) has a nice example. Every time you accept a client after reading the message you **need** to `close` the connection so the client knows that the recieve has ended.

Comment: edited! 
but after first client-server message transfer, the server shuts down. how can i make it so that the server doesnt shuts down instead keeps on listerning for next message

Comment: Got it fixed! thanks for your time! :)